# Can pytest fixtures be combined?

Tags: python, pytest

Can one fixture build on another in pytest? I have a very simple fixture called "cleaner" defined as:

```py
import pytest
from mypackage import db

@pytest.fixture()
def cleaner(request):
  def finalizer():
    db.clear()
  request.addfinalizer(finalizer)
```

then in my `setup.cfg` I have:

```
[pytest]
norecursedirs = .git venv
usefixtures = cleaner
```

This results in the database being truncated after each test, which is great. But now I want other fixtures I make to also call the finalizer from cleaner. Is there a way to define another fixture that somehow expands on or calls cleaner?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to declare that your other fixture depends on cleaner explicitly:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def cleaner(request):
  def finalizer():
    print '\n"cleaner" finalized'
  print '\n"cleaner" fixture'
  request.addfinalizer(finalizer)


@pytest.fixture
def other(cleaner):
    print '\n"other" fixture'


def test_foo(other):
    pass
```

Running this with `py.test -s -v` produces:

```
test_foo.py@16::test_foo
"cleaner" fixture

"other" fixture
PASSED
"cleaner" finalized
```

Comment: when i try this, i get fixture not found